# I want to Add a ToString method to HashTable(array implementation) class that prints the table position, key value, and data

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures, tostring

1. This is my attempt to code the ToString method but I'm not sure how to return all of this?
2. I want to  use a StringBuilder object and append all active items to it including their key value and the array index.

Below is the code

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < mTable.Length; i++)
    {
        if (mTable[i].Status == EntryType.Active)
        {
            s.Append(mTable[i].Value);
            s.Append(mTable[i]);

        }
        Console.WriteLine(mTable[i]);
        Console.WriteLine(mTable[i].Key);

    }

    //return "position" + mTable[].Value;


}
    //example of output

   //TableIndex  KEY  VALUE
   //0           NULL NULL
   //1           NULL NULL
   //2           100    256
   //3           101    852
   //4           NULL NULL
   //5           102   706
   //6           NULL NULL
```

Comment: `ToString` method, is not intended to print something, but rather provides a way to convert the object (Hashtable in your case) into an elegant string representation. So when you do `var ht = new HashTable(); Console.WriteLine(ht)`, it will print the `Hashtable` object in a better way (the default implementation will print just a reference id). If you want someone to provide a full example of `ToString` then you need to provide an example showing the contents of the HashTable and its expected string representation

Comment: An example would be
TableIndex  KEY  VALUE
0                 NULL NULL
1                 NULL NULL
2                 100    256
3                 101    852
4                 NULL NULL
5                 102   706
6                 NULL NULL

Answer (score 0):

You're most of the way there. You shouldn't do any output in the `ToString()` method itself. The `ToString()` method just return a string with no side effects.

Without seeing the `mTable` definition and the definition of the objects stored in the `mTable`, this is the best I can really provide.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0;i < mTable.Length; i++)
    {
        if (mTable[i].Status == EntryType.Active)
        {
            // Use s.Append() or s.AppendFormat() to build up your string
        }
    }

    return s.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel ... Use

```
return String.Concat(
  mTable.Where(w=>w.Status == EntryType.Active)
        .Select(s=>$"{s.Key}:{s.Value};")
)
```

for fancy outputs:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
        mTable.Select((s,i)=>new {Index=i, s.Key, s.Value, s.Status})
              .Where(w => w.Status == EntryType.Active)
              .Select(s => $"[{s.Index}]Key:{s.Key}=Value:{s.Value}")
        );
}
```

Done. Curious, no separators?